# Spyder Application Launch Error Causes Python To Quit Unexpectedly

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I apologize for any incorrect syntax, as I am very new to computers and software development. I have downloaded the latest version of Anaconda to run Spyder, however, whenever I try to launch the program it results in an Application Launch Error:

`//anaconda3/bin/pythonw: line 3: 89620 Segmentation fault: 11 //anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"`

Additionally, I receive an error report which informs me the Python quit unexpectedly
[python quit unexpectedly error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE9ue.png)

I am using Python version 3.11.4 and I am trying to launch Spyder version 5.4.3

I should also mention that I am using MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6

Please let me know if there is anything I can do

I have removed and re-installed Anaconda several times with no success. I have tried various things from similar posts unsuccessfully, however, nothing has worked.

I tried
`conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge spyder conda activate spyder spyder`
and it gave me a similar application launch error

I tried `conda update --all` and it did not help

I tried following this advice:

- open your terminal
- navigate to `/opt/anaconda3/bin`
- type `nano pythonw`
- the last line of the file should read `/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"`
- this line should be `/opt/anaconda3/python.app/pythonapp/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"` (the pythonapp part is missing)
- safe and close
- it should work now

but the instructions are not clear enough for me to follow, as `/opt/anaconda3/bin` results in an error message saying the file or directory does not exist, and I also get stuck in the terminal window after typing in `nano pythonw` and cannot do anything

I tried `conda install --force-reinstall python.app` and it did not help. I tried `conda update python python.app` but the package is already installed. I tried `conda install -f python.app` and even had Anaconda closed during the install, nor did I have anything else running that would be using Python, I only had Google Chrome open and the Preview Application open, however, this did not help either.